# How can I control the a application from a other form windows application in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to make a form Windows application in C# with just a button . when the user click on button the one of Browser google chrome or muzila or explorer become open and show the option or setting page of Browser .

Now I can open the browser with this cods . I need control the Browser for show options or refresh or Stop .

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe") ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start a specific website the code is:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.webpage.com");
```

If you want to start a specific browser at a specific website the code is:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore.exe", "http://www.webpage.com");
```

Comment: I believe this does not answer the question. He wants to open a specific browser at a specific address, not the default browser.